Why does my Container concept fail for const std::list<double> due to begin() and end() not satisfying the return-type requirements?
I am trying to define a Container concept in C++ that validates standard library containers, including std::list. However, the concept fails for const std::list<double> because the begin() and end() functions in std::list do not meet the expected return types for iterators in my concept. Specifically, they return iterator for non-const objects and const_iterator for const objects, and my current concept does not account for this distinction properly. How can I modify my concept to handle these cases correctly?
I tried adding checks using std::as_const but the issue persists. I expected the concept to pass for both const and non-const containers but need help addressing this mismatch.
template <typename C>
concept Container = requires(C c, const C cc) {
    typename C::value_type;
    typename C::reference;
    typename C::const_reference;
    typename C::iterator;
    typename C::const_iterator;
    typename C::difference_type;
    typename C::size_type;

    { c.begin() } -> std::convertible_to<typename C::iterator>;
    { c.end() } -> std::convertible_to<typename C::iterator>;

    { c.cbegin() } -> std::convertible_to<typename C::const_iterator>;
    { c.cend() } -> std::convertible_to<typename C::const_iterator>;

    { cc.begin() } -> std::convertible_to<typename C::const_iterator>;
    { cc.end() } -> std::convertible_to<typename C::const_iterator>;

    requires std::is_copy_constructible_v<C>;
};


std::remove_const_t<C>?

Would need something like { const_cast<const C&>(c).begin() } -> std::convertible_to<typename C::const_iterator>; What are test cases? template<Container T> void foo(T&& a) would fail with this.

Provide the concept validation code too. The snippet doesn't show how you test the concept. This is far from minimal reproducible sample.

`TEST(Container, basic){
static_assert(!Container);
static_assert(!Container);
Container auto c1 = std::list{};
static_assert(Container<decltype(c1)>);
const std::list c2 = {};
static_assert(Container<decltype(c2)>);
Container auto c3 = std::array<int,3>{1,2,3};
static_assert(Container<decltype(c3)>);
}`
sry this is how it is tested, thankfully jeff's solution works

You might edit the question to include that testing code (so question would be complete). In addition, block code is more readable in question than in comment ;-)

One just needs to test the const-removed version of C:
concept Container = requires(typename std::remove_const_t<C> c, const C cc) {
    ... /* keep the same */ ...
};

See https://godbolt.org/z/b4aMPdoWM

Container should also accept cv-ref qualified types, such as list&&, violate list, etc., so you can use the original concept for implementation details and wrap it (c.begin()/c.end() should exactly return C::iterator):
template <typename C>
concept ContainerImpl = std::copy_constructible<C> &&
  requires(C c, const C cc) {
    typename C::value_type;
    typename C::reference;
    typename C::const_reference;
    typename C::iterator;
    typename C::const_iterator;
    typename C::difference_type;
    typename C::size_type;

    { c.begin() } -> std::same_as<typename C::iterator>;
    { c.end() } -> std::same_as<typename C::iterator>;

    { c.cbegin() } -> std::same_as<typename C::const_iterator>;
    { c.cend() } -> std::same_as<typename C::const_iterator>;

    { cc.begin() } -> std::same_as<typename C::const_iterator>;
    { cc.end() } -> std::same_as<typename C::const_iterator>;
  };

template <typename C>
concept Container = ContainerImpl<std::remove_cvref_t<C>>;

